# Sqlite database to xml c#

Tags: c#, sql, xml, unity3d, sqlite

```
    public void SaveToXML()
{
    var sqc = new SqliteConnection(SqliteController.ActiveConnection);

    sqc.Open();

    var q = "select name_journal, Points.name_point,Workplace.name_workplace, Workplace.percent_workplace from Journal INNER JOIN Points ON Points.id_journal = Journal.id_journal INNER JOIN Workplace ON Workplace.id_point = Points.id_point";

    var sqd = new SqliteDataAdapter(q, sqc);

    var ds = new DataSet();

    sqd.Fill(ds, "adv");

    ds.WriteXml("d:/data.xml");
}
```

Пишу програмку на юнити, есть база данных, по определенному запросу нужно сохранить данные в xml формате, запрос написан выше. В итоге у меня что-то идет не так, созданный xml файл пуст. Переодически возникают ошибки о том, что он не может найти таблицы Points.name Workplace.name, также я не использую в проекте EF.

Comment: Может всётаки вот так `ds.WriteXml(@"d:\data.xml");`

Comment: Попробуйте наполнить `Fill`  `DataTable` вместо `DataSet`, с ним меньше мороки и легче трассировать. Боюсь что прийдётся трассировать.

Comment: Ничего не изменилось, проблема именно в синтаксисе запроса, потому что если написать select * from tableName, то все будет работать

Comment: Тогда, похоже вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. Да... сложно вникнуть в запрос когда видно 10% от всего запроса, если хотите что б другие вам помогли - сделайте так что б запрос было весь видно - добавьте возврат каретки. Хотя... лучше проверьте запрос в SQL-редакторе нормальном. А потом пришивайте в программу. Скорее всего упущена какая-то мелочь - и в редакторе будет видно.

Comment: @nick_n_a Fill принимает в качестве параметров только Dataset

Comment: Вопрос в том, как мне написать вот такой запрос, используя только синтаксис c# SELECT
Journal.name_journal,
Points.name_point,
Workplace.name_workplace,
Workplace.percent_workplace
FROM
Journal
INNER JOIN Points ON Points.id_journal = Journal.id_journal
INNER JOIN Workplace ON Workplace.id_point = Points.id_point

Comment: Попробуйте для начала диспозить `SqliteConnection` (оберните код в `using`).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Уже пробовал, но не помогло

Comment: @nick_n_a как раз запрос я сгенерировал в Sql редакторе, там по этому запросу хорошо выводится результат

Comment: У вас exception точно точно не возникает? Если да - проверяйте внимательно параметры вашего коннекта, возможно вы перепутали базу. Т.е. результат должен быть - либо пустая выборка, либо полная выборка либо exception.